# Magento2 Custom shipping method, select service

Tags: magento2, module, shipping-methods

I'm creating a custom shipping method on Magento2. I got the admin working ok. There are 3 different services it choose from, lets say "14hrs", 24hrs and Economy.

The problems comes in the front end, checkout page. I can see my Method, but I can't figure out how to display the select for the services. I've read several shipping method module tutorials, but none talks about this.

Currently this is my **CustomShipping.php**:

```
namespace TCK\ASM\Model\Carrier;

use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart;
use TCK\ASM\Model\Source\Method;
class ASMShipping extends \Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrier implements
    \Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\CarrierInterface
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_code = 'ASMShipping';

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory $rateErrorFactory
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory $rateResultFactory
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory $rateMethodFactory
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory $rateErrorFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory $rateResultFactory,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory $rateMethodFactory,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
        \TCK\ASM\Model\Source\MethodFactory $metodoFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_rateResultFactory = $rateResultFactory;
        $this->_rateMethodFactory = $rateMethodFactory;
        $this->_metodoFactory = $metodoFactory;
        parent::__construct($scopeConfig, $rateErrorFactory, $logger, $data);
        $this->cart = $cart;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllowedMethods()
    {
        return ['ASMShipping' => $this->getConfigData('name')];
    }

    /**
     * @param RateRequest $request
     * @return bool|Result
     */
    public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
    {
        if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
            return false;
        }

        $err = null;
        $envio = array();
        //Mage2
         /** @var \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result $result */
        $result = $this->_rateResultFactory->create(); 
        /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method $method */
        $method = $this->_rateMethodFactory->create(); 
        $method->setCarrier('ASMShipping');
        $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));
        $method->setMethod('ASMShipping');
        $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));
        /*you can fetch shipping price from different sources over some APIs, we used price from config.xml - xml node price*/
        //$amount = $this->getConfigData('handling_fee');
        $amount=0;

        $envio["cpOrg"]=$request->_data['postcode'];
        $envio["codPaisOrg"] = '34';
        $envio["cpDst"] = $request->_data['dest_postcode'];
        $envio["peso"] = $request->_data['package_weight'];
        $envio["bultos"] = 1;
        $envio["precioProducto"] = $request->_data['package_value'];


        $amount=$request->_data['package_value'];
        $method->setPrice($amount);
        $method->setCost($amount);

        $result->append($method);

        $items=$this->cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();

        return $result;

    /** end func **/
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution es this:
First I created a helper to manage the options (shipping methods) And then use it in the Model.

Helper:

```
namespace TCK\ASM\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use TCK\ASM\Model\Source\Method;

/**
 * Class Group
 * @package TCK\ASM\Helper
 */

    class Group extends AbstractHelper

{
    protected $resourceConnection;
    protected $asm;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resourceConnection,
        \TCK\ASM\Model\Source\Method $asm
    )
    {
        $this->resourceConnection = $resourceConnection;
        $this->asm = $asm;
    }
    /**
     * Stub
     * @return string
     */
    public function getGroupData($id)
    {

        $db = $this->resourceConnection->getConnection();
        $result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM customer_group WHERE customer_group_id=' . $id); 
        $row = $result->fetch();
        $values=$row['shipping_method'];
        $split=explode(",",$values);
        $count = count($split);

        $metodos=$this->asm->toOptionArray();

        $i=1;
        $s=0;
        for ($i; $i <= $count; $i++) {
            $info[$i]=$metodos[$split[$s]];
            $s++;
        }

        return $info;
    }

    public function getAllMethods()
    {
        $metodos=$this->asm->toOptionArray();

        return $metodos;
    }
}
```

Model:

```
namespace TCK\ASM\Model\Carrier;

use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrier;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\CarrierInterface;
use TCK\ASM\Model\Source\Method;
use TCK\ASM\Helper\Group;
class ASMShipping extends \Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrier implements
    \Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\CarrierInterface
{
    /**
     * Code of the carrier
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_code='ASMShipping';
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory
     */
    protected $_rateResultFactory;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory
     */
    protected $_rateMethodFactory;
    /**
     * Rate result data
     *
     * @var Result
     */
    protected $_result;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory $rateErrorFactory
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory $rateResultFactory
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory $rateMethodFactory
     * @param Cart $cart
     * @param \TCK\ASM\Helper\Group $helper
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList $directory_list
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory $rateErrorFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory $rateResultFactory,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory $rateMethodFactory,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList $directory_list,
        \TCK\ASM\Helper\Group $helper,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resourceConnection,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_rateResultFactory = $rateResultFactory;
        $this->_rateMethodFactory = $rateMethodFactory;
        $this->directory_list = $directory_list;
        $this->cart = $cart;
        $this->helper = $helper;
        $this->resourceConnection = $resourceConnection;
        parent::__construct($scopeConfig, $rateErrorFactory, $logger, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Returns array of key-value pairs of all available methods
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllowedMethods()
    {
        $group_info=$this->helper->getAllMethods();
        $carriers=array();
        foreach ($group_info as &$carrier) {
            $carriers[$group_info['label']]=$group_info['label'];
        }
        return $carriers;
    }

    /**
     * @param RateRequest $request
     * @return bool|Result|null
     */
    public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
    {
        if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
            return false;
        }


        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $customerSession = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');

        if ($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            $gid=$customerSession->getCustomerGroupId();
            $group_info=$this->helper->getGroupData($gid);
        }



        $err = null;
        $envio = array();
        /** @var \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result $result */
        //$result = $this->_rateResultFactory->create();
        $this->_result = $this->_rateResultFactory->create();
        /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method $method */
        $method = $this->_rateMethodFactory->create();
        $method->setCarrier('ASMShipping');
        $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));
        $method->setMethod('ASMShipping');
        $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));
        $amount=0;

        //Shipping logic         

        $ASM10=$this->_getQuote(0,$precioPeso, $archivo, $usarTableRate, $cp_cliente, $envio["peso"], $pais_cliente);
        $ASM14=$this->_getQuote(1,$precioPeso, $archivo, $usarTableRate, $cp_cliente, $envio["peso"], $pais_cliente);
        $ASM24=$this->_getQuote(2,$precioPeso, $archivo, $usarTableRate, $cp_cliente, $envio["peso"], $pais_cliente);
        $ECONOMY=$this->_getQuote(3,$precioPeso, $archivo, $usarTableRate, $cp_cliente, $envio["peso"], $pais_cliente);

        return $this->getResult();
    }
    /**
     * Get result of request
     * @return Result
     */
    public function getResult()
    {
        return $this->_result;
    }

    /**
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _getQuote($grupo, $precioPeso, $archivo, $usarTableRate, $cp_cliente, $peso, $pais_cliente)
    {

        $group_info=$this->helper->getAllMethods();
        $servicio = $group_info[$grupo]['label'];
        $envio["metodo"]["servicio"]=$group_info[$grupo]['servicio'];
        $envio["metodo"]["horario"]=$group_info[$grupo]['horario'];
        /*Tarifas*/
        $tarifas = array();
        //Logic stuff


        $rate = $this->_rateMethodFactory->create();
        $rate->setCarrier($this->_code);
        $rate->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));
        $rate->setMethodTitle($group_info[$grupo]['label']);
        $rate->setPrice($importe);
        $rate->setCost(0);
        $this->_result->append($rate);
        return $this;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hello Oscar Azpeitia, above answer is working perfect for your question?

Comment: Yes @PayalPatel it is!

Comment: Ok, @OscarAzpeitia, Your model call using di.xml or config.xml ?

Comment: @PayalPatel di.xml

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
namespace Mageplaza\Simpleshipping\Model\Carrier;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result;
class Shipping extends \Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrier implements
\Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\CarrierInterface
{
/**
 * @var string
 */
protected $_code = 'simpleshipping';

/**
 * @var \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory
 */
protected $_rateResultFactory;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory
 */
protected $_rateMethodFactory;

/**
 * Shipping constructor.
 *
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface          $scopeConfig
 * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory  $rateErrorFactory
 * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface                                    $logger
 * @param \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory                  $rateResultFactory
 * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory $rateMethodFactory
 * @param array                                                       $data
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory $rateErrorFactory,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
    \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory $rateResultFactory,
    \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory $rateMethodFactory,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_rateResultFactory = $rateResultFactory;
    $this->_rateMethodFactory = $rateMethodFactory;
    parent::__construct($scopeConfig, $rateErrorFactory, $logger, $data);
}

/**
 * get allowed methods
 * @return array
 */
public function getAllowedMethods()
{
    return [$this->_code => $this->getConfigData('name')];
}

/**
 * @return float
 */
private function getShippingPrice()
{
    $configPrice = $this->getConfigData('price');

    $shippingPrice = $this->getFinalPriceWithHandlingFee($configPrice);

    return $shippingPrice;
}

/**
 * @param RateRequest $request
 * @return bool|Result
 */
public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
{
    if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
        return false;
    }

    /** @var \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result $result */
    $result = $this->_rateResultFactory->create();

    /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method $method */
    $method = $this->_rateMethodFactory->create();

    $method->setCarrier($this->_code);
    $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));

    $method->setMethod($this->_code);
    $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));

    $amount = $this->getShippingPrice();

    $method->setPrice($amount);
    $method->setCost($amount);

    $result->append($method);

    return $result;
}
}
```